# Hosting VMs for a final exam

Tags: virtual-machines, hosting, cloud

I want to host 20 copies of the same VM for a final exam I am giving in a Computer Science class.  The campus resources have proven extremely unreliable and I'm looking for alternative solutions.  Ideas are:

- Host them on my home server and direct students there
- Go to some commercial cloud service

If I host them myself, is there a back-of-the-envelope way to see if my home server has sufficient resources to handle this?

If I host with some provider like AWS (or similar) is the cost manageable (ie, under $50 USD for 20 servers running for 8 hours)?

Are there other solutions I should be considering?

Comment: What will the VMs be used for? This would heavily influence answers.

Comment: @TorinCarey They are CTF images: a web server is running on port 80 with some vulnerable services; eventually the students can SSH in and then in turn use several techniques to escalate to root, which completes the exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not host such a thing at home.

Chances are your home setup has many single points of failure. (i.e. you have only one power source, only one internet connection, only one physical machine)

And if anything goes wrong during the exam you have no one to shift the blame onto.

Instead what you need to do first is to speak to the people responsible for the infrastructure on campus about your needs. If the exam takes place on campus you will likely be depending on the campus internet connection anyway if you choose hosting elsewhere.

If the system administrators for the facilities on campus cannot provide you with the resources to run that many VMs, but they can guarantee you redundant internet connections from the exam venue to the internet backbone, then you can start considering cloud providers.

If you end up going with a cloud provider there is a few things to keep in mind:

- Speak to the cloud provider's support in advance to ensure that resources will be available on the day.
- Spin up the VMs multiple hours in advance, maybe even the evening before the exam. While this will of course increase the cost it will reduce the risk significantly.
- Avoid using pre-emptible VMs (or whatever terminology your chosen cloud provider has for that kind of thing). The money you'd save simply isn't worth the risk that the provider decide to give the resources to a more important customer in the middle of your exam.
- Avoid most single points of failure by having resources in two independent regions, such that the exam can continue even if one cloud region goes offline during the exam.

Possibly you may end up going with hosting on campus with fall back to a cloud provider. This however only makes sense if your campus system administrators can give better guarantees for the networking than they can for the computing resources.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't take this approach. Thats too much work and a waste of time. There is too much repetition in configuration and room for error. It also is a terrible way to scale if later on you take on more students. Your job is to teach, not be an IT administrator.

Use someone else's web infrastructure that has been battle tested. There are many Internet service companies that provide a platform for taking tests over the web. An example is [ClassMarker](https://www.classmarker.com).